# Unable to order softlayer VSI from slcli

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

**Softlayer SLCLI VSI order issue:**

While ordering VSI from Slcli using the following order details got error message "SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_NotFound): Unable to find price for core capacity of 1642."

Please help if you are facing such issues or is there any values which i am missing over here.

Following SLCLI command line

```
15:05:15nirav@NiravsMac~/Downloads/ArraySSLVPN $ slcli virtual create
Hostname: niravtest.win.com
Domain: windo.com
Cpu: 1642
Memory: 4096
Datacenter: dal05
Operating System Code: 175777
This action will incur charges on your account. Continue? [y/N]: y
SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_NotFound): Unable to find price for core capacity of 1642.
16:06:30nirav@NiravsMac~/Downloads/ArraySSLVPN $ slcli virtual create
Hostname: niravtest.win.com
Domain: win.com
Cpu: 1964
Memory: 4096
Datacenter: dal09
Operating System Code: 175777
This action will incur charges on your account. Continue? [y/N]: y
SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_NotFound): Unable to find price for core capacity of 1964.
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue is that you are sending wrong data, the CPU = 1642 values does not exist, you need to send the CPU capacity such as 2 cores, 4 cores etc. So you need to repalce the value "1642" for "4" or for the capacity of CPU that you want.

In order to see the full list of valid values to create the VM you can call:

```
$ slcli virtual create-options
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks Nelson for your comment it helped i guess in my cli i was using OS code which was not known to us on anyway however after i used "WIN_2012-STD-R2_64" it did take and provision went fine.